# How do I set a background-color for the width of text, not the width of the entire element, using only CSS?

Tags: html, css

What I want is for the green background to be just behind the text, not to be 100% of the page width. Here is my current code:

```css
h1 { 
    text-align: center; 
    background-color: green; 
}
```

```html
<h1>The Last Will and Testament of Eric Jones</h1>
```

Note that I cannot edit the HTML. So I cannot add an inner element like a `<span>` nor can i insert one with javascript, etc.

Comment: Can this be done without putting a span in?

Comment: To avoid adding the span you could have changed the < h1 > display property from block to inline (catch is you would have ensure the elements after the < h1 > are block elements.

Comment: Wondering what you ended up doing? So many of the better options for answers mentioned changing the HTML, but at that time on the project you were not able to.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

Put the text in an [inline element](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/inline.html), such as a `<span>`.

```
<h1><span>The Last Will and Testament of Eric Jones</span></h1>
```

And then apply the background color on the inline element.

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center; 
}
h1 span { 
    background-color: green; 
}
```

An inline element is as big as its contents is, so that should do it for you.

Comment: @tom: You can use JavaScript to put a span in.

Comment: thanks, but I only have permission to modify the CSS. Nevermind.

Comment: just add the display css rule to the h1 selector, you won't have to add a <span> tag. Like this:
`h1 { 
display:inline;
}`

Comment: display:table is a better choice... to avoid the problem highlighted in the comments section in the next reply. display:inline will concatenate <h1> and <h2> to be in same line.... when they are originally in next lines.

Answer (score 119):

## Option 1

**`display: table;`**

- no parent required

```css
h1 {
    display: table; /* keep the background color wrapped tight */
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto; /* keep the table centered */
    padding:5px;font-size:20px;background-color:green;color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<h1>The Last Will and Testament of Eric Jones</h1>
```

**fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/J7VBV/293/

**more**

`display: table` tells the element to behave as a normal HTML table would.

More about it at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp), [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/#display-table) and [here](http://www.mattboldt.com/kicking-ass-with-display-table/)

---

## Option 2

**`display: inline-flex;`**

- requires `text-align: center;` on parent

```css
.container {
    text-align: center; /* center the child */
}
h1 {
    display: inline-flex; /* keep the background color wrapped tight */
    padding:5px;font-size:20px;background-color:green;color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>The Last Will and Testament of Eric Jones</h1>
</div>
```

---

## Option 3

**`display: flex;`**

- requires a flex parent container

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* center the child */
}
h1 {
    display: flex;
    /* margin: 0 auto; or use auto left/right margin instead of justify-content center */
    padding:5px;font-size:20px;background-color:green;color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <h1>The Last Will and Testament of Eric Jones</h1>
    </div>
```

**about**

Probably the most popular guide to Flexbox and one I reference constantly is at [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

---

## Option 4

**`display: block;`**

- requires a flex parent container

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* centers child */
}
h1 {
    display: block;
    padding:5px;font-size:20px;background-color:green;color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>The Last Will and Testament of Eric Jones</h1>
</div>
```

---

## Option 5

**`::before`**

- requires entering words in css file (not very practical)

```css
h1 {
    display: flex; /* set a flex box */
    justify-content: center; /* so you can center the content like this */
}

h1::before {
    content:'The Last Will and Testament of Eric Jones'; /* the content */
    padding: 5px;font-size: 20px;background-color: green;color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<h1></h1>
```

**fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/J7VBV/457/

**about**

More about css pseudo elements ::before and ::after at [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/) and pseudo elements in general at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)

---

## Option 6

**`display: inline-block;`**

- centering with `position: absolute` and `translateX`
- requires a `position: relative` parent

```css
.container {
  position: relative; /* required for absolute positioned child */
}
h1 {
  display: inline-block; /* keeps container wrapped tight to content */
  position: absolute; /* to absolutely position element */
  top: 0;
  left: 50%; /* part1 of centering with translateX/Y */
  transform: translateX(-50%); /* part2 of centering with translateX/Y */
  white-space: nowrap; /* text lines will collapse without this */
  padding:5px;font-size:20px;background-color:green;color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
  <h1>The Last Will and Testament of Eric Jones</h1>
```

**about**

More on centering with `transform: translate();` (and centering in general) in [this CSS tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/#both-unknown)

---

## Option 7

**`text-shadow:` and `box-shadow:`**

- not what the OP was looking for but maybe helpful to others finding their way here.

```css
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {display: table;margin: 10px auto;padding: 5px;font-size: 20px;color: #ffffff;overflow:hidden;}
h1 {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px green,0 0 5px green,
                 0 0 5px green,0 0 5px green,
                 0 0 5px green,0 0 5px green,
                 0 0 5px green,0 0 5px green;
}
h2 {
    text-shadow: -5px -5px 5px green,-5px 5px 5px green,
                  5px -5px 5px green,5px 5px 5px green;
}
h3 {
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.8);
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px hsla(120, 100%, 25%, 0.5),
                 0 0 10px hsla(120, 100%, 25%, 0.5),
                 0 0 10px hsla(120, 100%, 25%, 0.5),
                 0 0 5px hsla(120, 100%, 25%, 1),
                 0 0 5px hsla(120, 100%, 25%, 1),
                 0 0 5px hsla(120, 100%, 25%, 1);
}
h4 { /* overflow:hidden is the key to this one */
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 35px green,0px 0px 35px green,
                 0px 0px 35px green,0px 0px 35px green;
}
h5 { /* set the spread value to something larger than you'll need to use as I don't believe percentage values are accepted */
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1000px green;
}
```

```html
<h1>The First Will and Testament of Eric Jones</h1>
<h2>The 2nd Will and Testament of Eric Jones</h2>
<h3>The 3rd Will and Testament of Eric Jones</h3>
<h4>The Last Will and Testament of Eric Jones</h4>
<h5>The Last Box and Shadow of Eric Jones</h5>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/t8L9Ly8o/

## More Options

There are a few other ways to go about this by combining the different display options and centering methods above.

Comment: Doing this with no containers and no pseudo-elements is simply awesome! Had no idea that the `display: table` could be so powerful, but I appreciate that you provided working alternatives.

Comment: this is the most thorough answer I've seen on this site. Well done

Answer (score 58):

A little late to game but thought I would add my 2 cents...

To avoid adding the extra mark-up of an inner span you could change the `<h1>` display property from `block` to `inline` (catch is you would have ensure the elements after the `<h1>` are block elements.

**HTML**

```
<h1>  
The Last Will and Testament of
Eric Jones</h1> 
<p>Some other text</p>
```

**CSS**

```
h1{
    display:inline;
    background-color:green;
    color:#fff;
}
```

**Result**
[image]

JSFIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/J7VBV/

Comment: Correct? Really? This way the heading is not centered anymore (because it's displayed inline). OP's question clearly includes the requirement for a centered heading.

Comment: @BalusC - No where in the original question does the OP specifically state the heading has to be centered. The question clearly asks how to make the green background not go full width. #justSaying

Comment: OP's screenshot and OP's initial CSS implies otherwise.

Comment: That maybe, but we are talking specifics here - not assumptions.

Comment: this has added problem in cases.. where if <h1> and <h2> tags are immediately in next lines... then <h1> and <h2> will then be displayed on the same line. The below display:table option is a good choice if you don't want to change the source code of the <h1> <h2> tags itself... but only change the css.

Answer (score 12):

As the other answers note, you can add a `background-color` to a `<span>` around your text to get this to work.

In the case where you have `line-height` though, you will see gaps. To fix this you can add a `box-shadow` with a little bit of grow to your span. You will also want `box-decoration-break: clone;` for FireFox to render it properly.

EDIT: If you're getting issues in IE11 with the box-shadow, try adding an `outline: 1px solid [color];` as well for IE only.

Here's what it looks like in action:

[image: example of the css technique]

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

h2 > span {
  background-color: #D32;
  color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: -10px 0px 0 7px #D32,
    10px 0px 0 7px #D32,
    0 0 0 7px #D32;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2><span>A HEADLINE WITH BACKGROUND-COLOR PLUS BOX-SHADOW :3</span></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: great tip adding the box-shadow - makes up the padding nicely. Thank you!

Comment: can we also remove the extra red color from text padding?

Comment: @Gaurav "Text padding" what do you mean? If you're talking about the line-height gaps, you'd want to remove the `box-shadow` and decrease `line-height`. If you still have "padding", you might need a negative `line-height` due to the font having baked in metrics that make it hard to style. You could also pull the font into something like font forge and modify the metrics directly. Might want to open a new question

Comment: got it, will try

Comment: With semi-transparent background color, this option does not render correctly.

Comment: @AtulYadav That's going to be really tough, considering the boxes the browser will create can overlap between broken lines. The closest I could get was using borders instead of box-shadow, but aligning it between different browsers to not overlap is not possible. See https://jsfiddle.net/m4z0xeb8/

Comment: This is the actual answer to the question. All others have some show-stopper.

Answer (score 9):

A very simple trick to do so, is to add a `<span>` tag and add background color to that. It will look just the way you want it.

```
<h1>  
    <span>The Last Will and Testament of Eric Jones</span>
</h1>
```

And CSS

```
h1 { text-align: center; }
h1 span { background-color: green; }
```

#### **WHY?**

`<span>` tag in an inline element tag, so it will only span over the content faking the effect.

Answer (score 6):

## EDIT: the answer below would apply in most cases. OP however later mentioned that they could not edit anything other than the CSS file. But will leave this here so it may be of use to others.

[image]

The main consideration that others are neglecting is that OP has stated that they cannot modify the HTML.

You can target what you need in the DOM then add classes dynamically with javascript. Then style as you need.

In an example that I made, I targeted all `<p>` elements with jQuery and wrapped it with a div with a class of "colored"

```
$( "p" ).wrap( "<div class='colored'></div>" );
```

Then in my CSS i targeted the `<p>` and gave it the background color and changed to `display: inline`

```
.colored p {
    display: inline;
    background: green;
}
```

By setting the display to inline you lose some of the styling that it would normally inherit. So make sure that you target the most specific element and style the container to fit the rest of your design. This is just meant as a working starting point. Use carefully. Working demo on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mMZwWG)

Answer (score 4):

Try removing the text-alignment center and center the `<h1>` or `<div>` the text resides in.

```
h1 {
    background-color:green;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

h1 is a block level element. You will need to use something like span instead as it is an inline level element (ie: it does not span the whole row).

In your case, I would suggest the following:

style.css

```
.highlight 
{
   background-color: green;
}
```

html

```
<span class="highlight">only the text will be highlighted</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

can use html5 **mark** tag within paragraph and heading tag.

```html
<p>lorem ipsum <mark>Highlighted Text</mark> dolor sit.</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Without changing html markup**

If you do not wish to change any of your `html` tags you can use:

```
h1 {
    background-color: green;  
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**With changing html markup**

This can be done using the HTML5 `<mark>` tag.

HTML:

```
<h1><mark>The Last Will and Testament of Eric Jones</mark></h1>
```

CSS:

```
mark
{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: OP needed a CSS only solution

Comment: @JGallardo true but maybe he just wants a non-Javascript solution and doesn't mind using the `mark` tag with `css`. If not, then this may still be useful to others.

Comment: @JGallardo I've edited my answer to show a solution that doesn't involve changing the html markup

Comment: mark does not work inside textarea element :(

Answer (score 3):

### Easily :

```
<p>lorem ibsum....</p>
```

with styles :

```
p{
    background-color: #eee;
    display: inline;
}
```

---

the background sets to the whole size of the element;
revise the diffrence between inline elements and block elements [from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    visibility: hidden;
}

h1:after {
    content:'The Last Will and Testament of Eric Jones';
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding: 5px;
    top: 10px;
    left: calc(30% - 5px);
}
```

Please note that **calc** is not compatible to all browsers :) Just want to be consistent with the alignment in the original post.

https://jsfiddle.net/richardferaro/ssyc04o4/

Answer (score 0):

`<mark>` tag with `background-color` helped me.

**Input:**

```
<p>
    Effective <mark style="background-color: light-gray">Nov 1, 2022</mark> We will be lowering our price.
</p>
```

**Output:**
Effective `Nov 1, 2022` We will be lowering our price.

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61610535/3411787)

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

```
<h1>
  <span>
    inline text<br>
      background padding<br>
      with box-shadow
  </span>
</h1>
```

**Css**

```
h1{
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 13px; //Padding on the sides so as not to stick.


  span {  
    background: #111; // background color
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.3; //The height of indents between lines.
    box-shadow: 13px 0 0 #111, -13px 0 0 #111; // Indents for each line on the sides.
  }
}
```

[Demo on codepen](https://codepen.io/tiigrus/pen/wNBLgN)

Comment: Firefox requires `box-decoration-break: clone;`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break

Answer (score -2):

You have to mention the width of the h1 tag..

your css will be like this

```
h1 {
text-align: center;
background-color: green;
width: 600px;
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

HTML

```
<h1 class="green-background"> Whatever text you want. </h1>
```

CSS

```
.green-background { 
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px; /*Optional (Padding is just for a better style.)*/
    background-color: green; 
}
```

Comment: Any answer that is code-only could be made much more useful to people looking for a solution to this problem if you could add some context to your answer.

Answer (score -3):

```html
<h1 style="display:inline-block;text-align: center;background : red;">The Last Will and Testament of Eric Jones</h1>
```

Comment: Well. That's some code. Just some code. It is completely free of explanation. It has the side effect of changing how the heading behaves in relation to the content around it. It says nothing that https://stackoverflow.com/a/32919558/19068 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/20257339/19068 haven't both said already

Comment: The user mentioned that they cannot change the HTML, adding an inline style is changing the HTML file.