# Getting background-color of display block to fill only behind text

Tags: html, css

I ran into a situation where I have a link that is set as a `display:block`. I'm trying to fill the background-color property with a color, but only behind the text; instead, it's filling the entire background of that row, which is logical, but not what I want. How can I fill only the background of the text without being an inline element? Or is this not possible?

HTML:

```
<a href ="#">mylink</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    display:block;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Please include your relevant HTML and CSS. You're also misspelling the properties; they are `background-color` and `color`.

Comment: i am in Australia, we spell it different here auto spell check : )...the html and css is not needed

Comment: You are incorrect. The HTML and CSS *is* needed according to the guidelines of the site. You also may spell the words differently, but you don't spell the properties differently. CSS is spelled the same no matter what country you're in.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310154/how-do-i-set-background-color-of-text-only-in-css

Comment: `a {display:inline-block;}` should do the trick. assuming that's the whole of the HTML.

Comment: updated but I thought the question was self explanatory

Comment: have to keep as block,inline elements cant have transformations applied to them

Comment: @Paulie_D different question if you read i must keep as block , its not a duplicate

Comment: Have you tried my answer - just wrap the text in a span and apply background colour to that?

Comment: yes and it was right, i chose yours...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to keep the link as a block, you can wrap the text in a `<span>` and apply the background colour to that.

Comment: Thanks it solved my issue, i wasn't sure, i was trying all display types and was contemplating on adding a dummy div you saved me a lot of time Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simple code would be something like this:

```
<a href="#" style="display: block">
 Hello<span style="background: blue; color: white">blue</span>link
</a>
```

You can then add padding and other style to the span tag. 
You can add a ID tag to the span if its a special once off thing for specific styling.