# Background-color only on the text field

Tags: html, css

this is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="hello">
Hello
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#hello {
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

As you can see in the fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/en27xg3b/), the background color is on all the div. I want it to be only where the "Hello" is.

I'm pretty sure it's a simple code, but I forget how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set background color of text only in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310154/how-do-i-set-background-color-of-text-only-in-css)

Comment: Try googling for "background color on text only".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your text inside a span. Like this

```css
#hello span{
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="hello">
  <span>Hello</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, I tried to do it with <p> instead of <span>. Thanks

Comment: Ten minutes and I'll can do it. haha

Comment: okay. thanks. and also `p` tag is a block level element by default so it covers full width.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `inline-block` or `inline`: https://jsfiddle.net/en27xg3b/1/

```css
#hello {
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:red;
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="hello">Hello</div>
```

---

2. Or wrap the text in a `span`: https://jsfiddle.net/en27xg3b/2/

```css
#hello span {
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="hello"><span>Hello</span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

`<div>` tag is display `block` so it fill background full.

In this case, You only set `display : inline;` for `<div>` tag

Like this https://jsfiddle.net/en27xg3b/4/

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text_background

but what you can do is have a style

```
<style>
span.highlight {
  background-color:red;
}
</style>
```

now in your html you can do

```
<div id="hello">
  <span class="highlight">
    Hello
   </span>
   More Text
</div>
```