# How to revert width:100% to just the length of the text?

Tags: css

The blue background is 100% `width` and I just want it to be as wide as the text.

https://codepen.io/TylerL-uxai/pen/gRxMqG

```css
.ux {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #3c99cd;
  background: rgba(60, 153, 205, 0.85);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-img-ux">
  <h2 class="ux">User Experience Design</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove right: 0;

Comment: do you want it to be positioned at the bottom center of the page still?

Comment: @JoelGlovacki bottom left yep

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310154/how-do-i-set-background-color-of-text-only-in-css

Comment: display: inline doesn't fix it, @DawnBringer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.ux {
  margin:0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.ux span {
  background: #3c99cd;
  background: rgba(60, 153, 205, 0.85);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-img-ux">
  <h2 class="ux"><span>User Experience Design</span></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: @user6582640 in which browser? try adding display:inline-block?

Comment: <h2 class="ai" style="display: inline"> doesn't fix it either. Crap lol

Comment: @user6582640 oop, just looked at your codepen link. try wrapping in a `span` tag with the background color applied to that. https://codepen.io/saetia/pen/XgedBz

Comment: Thank you @Joel!!