# How to change the background color of TEXT in css

Tags: html, css

Let's take for example :

```
<div id="div1">This is a sentence.</div>
```

The `<div>` fill up 100% of the line.

The text itself, just a little portion of that.

I want to give the text a background color WITHOUT giving the whole line a background color.

I can change the html and add a `span` of course. (And use this span with `background-color`)

```
<div id="div1"><span>This is a sentence.</span></div>
```

But is it possible in pure css, without changing the html ?

PS : I'm making a css code for `hyper` terminal.

**SOLUTION** (for all div) :

```
div{display:table;}
```

This totally destroy `tmux` behavior (inside `hyper`) but maybe i'm asking for too much...

`echo -e "\n\n"` also becomes a problem. :p

SOLUTION FOR THIS PROBLEM : (empty div take no space)

```
div:after{content: " ";}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set background color of text only in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310154/how-do-i-set-background-color-of-text-only-in-css)

Comment: This isn't really possible in pure css, except for some rather clunky solutions. The best would be to change the markup, if you can.

Comment: Your best bet is `display:table-cell` - Detailed answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:table-cell`

> table-cell:   Let the element behave like a `<td>` element - [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Also, unless you want to go back to the dark ages, this is [well-supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)

```css
#div1 {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">This is a sentence.</div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pri cu quod audiam molestie, sit an modo probo conceptam, vim nemore quodsi no. Postea possit ne pro. Ne mel mollis oportere laboramus. Eu dico eius omnes ius. Id vis nibh adipiscing, maiorum suscipit ius eu. Sonet viris antiopam
nec in, est id equidem omnesque cotidieque, tritani detraxit qui cu.
```

Comment: Using `inline-block` or `table-cell` in my example is just breaking `hyper`. (line breaks), But thanks to your idea, i found out that `display:table;` did the trick. ;)

Comment: @bobdylan Great! I am glad you figured that out. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:before` to apply CSS on

```css
#div1 {
  color: blue; // hide original text
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

#div1:before {
  content: 'This is a sentence.';
  background-color: purple;
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">This is a sentence.</div>
```

---

If you do not need `#div1` to be full width, than simply apply `#div1 {display: inline-block}` to it and it will act as `span` element

Comment: Ugly, but probably the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Block element always takes the width as 100% while inline block takes the width of the element itself. so try using inline block CSS to the element inside a div]
`Display:inline-block;`

[1](https://codepen.io/nazarbecks/pen/GEMdaG)
**As for eg:**

```
[https://codepen.io/nazarbecks/pen/GEMdaG][1]
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/nazarbecks/pen/GEMdaG)

Answer (score -3):

you can set `#div1` as `inline-block`.

```
#div1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: color;
}
```