# background size of p tag

Tags: html, css

i am trying to reduce the size of the background color of p element so it fits only  on the number and i don't know what css property to use ?

this is what i have actually : 
[image]

this is a p tag :

```css
#totalValue {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<p id="totalValue"> 0 </p>
```

i want to have the green only on the number like this :
[image]

is it possible ?

Comment: <span>...</span> || display: inline-block / inline-flex / inline-grid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the background color of targeted text only, using only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310154/how-do-i-set-the-background-color-of-targeted-text-only-using-only-css)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this may help you:

```css
#totalValue {
  background-color: green;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p id="totalValue"> 0 </p>
```

Or you can use `float:left;` instead of `display:inline-block;`

Comment: Preferably OP should use `display: inline-block;` instead of `float: left;` for this in case OP wants the text to float right or other things.

Also you should use the ID-attribute for scripts and the class-attribute for CSS styling.

Comment: from all the possiblities you used the bad one :p

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:-

```
#totalValue {    
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `display` property with the `inline-block` value:

```
#totalValue {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```