# How to fit span background-color size to text in container using css

Tags: html, css

I want to fit span background-color to text size in parent container.
The problem is the container already have css properties. 
I can make some change but this properties are parsed dynamicaly.

For now it's like this:

[image]

It need to be like this:

[image: Imgur]

I already tried methods from [How do I set the background color of targeted text only, using only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310154/how-do-i-set-the-background-color-of-targeted-text-only-using-only-css) but non of this works becouse of css properties from parent element

```
<div>
  <span>  
The Last Will and Testament of
Eric Jones dsamd kaldmlsakd msalkd maslk dmaslkd maskld msalkd amsdlk asmdlk asmdkl asmd klsam dlkask dasmd lksamd lkasmd lskadm lksad mlsakd mlsak
  </span>
</div>
```

```
div{
  top: 10px; 
  left: 10px; 
  width: 450px; 
  height: 180px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: none;
  border-color: #FFF000;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: dotted;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAA1BMVEX/AAAZ4gk3AAAASElEQVR4nO3BgQAAAADDoPlTX+AIVQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADwDcaiAAFXD1ujAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
  background-color: #ff0000;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  text-align: left;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
}
span{
    background-color:blue;
    display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Shinen/jom70fv6/34/

Maybe there is a way to make changes in span style to make it work?

Best wishes :)

## SOLUTION

The soultion what i found is to put span into another container.
Maybe someone have better idea?
https://jsfiddle.net/Shinen/jom70fv6/37/

Comment: @Shizukura if you run jsfiddle you will see the problem.

Comment: You can't do this while the span is a flex-item &/or `display:block` - https://jsfiddle.net/2pwtebgf/

Answer (score 0):

```
span {
    width: min-content;
}
```

Setting the `width` of the span tag to `min-content` worked for me.

Comment: It doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/0sk3h21u/

Answer (score -1):

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/jth3x0u9/) is my working example

the code is here:

```
 div{
  top: 10px; 
  left: 10px; 
  width: 450px; 
  height: 180px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: none;
  border-color: #FFF000;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: dotted;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAA1BMVEX/AAAZ4gk3AAAASElEQVR4nO3BgQAAAADDoPlTX+AIVQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADwDcaiAAFXD1ujAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
  background-color: #ff0000;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  text-align: left;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
}
span {
  background-color: blue; 
}
p{
  text-align: justify;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<p><span>The Last Will and Testament of
Eric Jones dsamd kaldmlsakd msalkd maslk dmaslkd maskld msalkd amsdlk asmdlk asmdkl asmd klsam dlkask dasmd lksamd lkasmd lskadm lksad mlsakd mlsak
</span></p>
</div>
```

**Update:** I just fixed the whole code, justified the text (just like in the image) and change the color to blue.

Comment: This is *close* but does not give the result required by the OP.