# Apply styling only on the text inside a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a `div` in `HTML` which is dynamically creating from the server side. I want to apply `css` in `HTML`(front-end) only on that `div` **if and only if its having some-content**. If it doesn't have any content then I have no need to apply the new styling.

**The sample of `HTML` code is:**

```
<div class="attr-marker">
    Some-text-content        <!-- Apply New Styling on it -->
</div>

<div class="attr-marker">
    <!-- No need of new styling -->
</div>

<div class="attr-marker">
    <!-- No need of new styling -->
    <i class="fas fa-car" style="color:#d42424;font-size:px"></i>
</div>
```

And the `CSS` which I tried but failed is:

```
.attr-marker text {
    display: block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 12px;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

I can achieve it by using `javascript` but I want purely `CSS` solution so it'll help me to minimize the code.

Comment: what is text in css style selector?

Comment: It can be any text inside the `div` having `class: attr-marker`.

Comment: i don't think it exists. tag name "text" is not present in w3 docs.

Comment: Yes I know. It was just a sample.

Comment: okay. understood.

Comment: Didn't find any better `CSS` solution for my query. I've to go with `JS`. :-(

Comment: You know there's no hope when 4 out of the 5 answers in a post has zero upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

You can set default style for empty div by using `:empty` pseudo selector. And then for regular div, just set the style as given above.

Or you can use `:not(:empty)` Pseudo Selector to set the style for the div that is not empty.

Here's an example:

```
.attr-marker:not(:empty) {
    display: block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 12px;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Let me know in case you have any questions.

Regards,

AJ

Comment: It seems that whitespaces and icons make the div as not empty. You could remove all the whitespaces in the div if you could (including the newline) and then try to make it work. Otherwise, it seems jQuery or JavaScript might be the only option.

Comment: Ignore **and icons** in my above comment. Put it by mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:empty` pseudo-class. However your server will need to output the .attr-marker div with no whitespace.

Like...

`<div class="attr-marker"></div>`

not

```
<div class="attr-marker">
</div>
```

And then the css would be,

```
.attr-marker:empty {
    display: block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 12px;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Additional reading, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

Comment: Here's an example, https://jsfiddle.net/wu9jc8xd/6/. I think think is what you meant?

Comment: I want `<div class="attr-marker">text</div>` in your very first tag on `jsfiddle`.

Comment: Ok you'll want to this then, https://jsfiddle.net/wu9jc8xd/7/. I think @AJ7 already mentioned. The reason the second div has styling applied to it in the example is because of white space.

Answer (score 0):

Either add another class to that div from the server side if it will send content or wrap content with another element and give it some styling.

Edit:

If you know exact position of your element then you can select it with nth-child pseudo-class:

```
.attr-marker:nth-child(1):not(:empty) {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: What if I'm unauthorized to get server access!! :-P

Answer (score 0):

Writing `.attr-marker text { }` means you want to access child elements with tag `text` of class `attr-maker`. No such tag exists in HTML.

There are specific [CSS text](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp) and [CSS font](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp) properties which work only on text. They are to be used in the text's parent element (in your case `div` with class name `attr-marker`):

```
.attr-marker {
    /* text properties */
    /* some other properties */
}
```

Properties like `display: block;`, `width: 12px;`, `height: 12px;` and so on, won't work on text.

That being said, you don't need to worry whether your CSS properties will be applied to the text or to the whole `div`. If you're using the right properties, you can be sure they are only applied to the text.

---

As for the content(text) presence, you don't need to worry about it. If there is no text, CSS won't change anything.

Comment: i know about `.attr-marker text { }`, It was just for sample. And I want `text-background` also in styling which is not available.

Comment: This is CSS. You can't ask for the `text-background` property if it is not available in the CSS. Changing text background is achieved in [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310154/how-do-i-set-a-background-color-for-the-width-of-text-not-the-width-of-the-enti)

Answer (score 0):

If these markers are block rendered elements, the browser should not display them, unless they have content, therefore you can trust the browser to not render the elements with no content, use the max-width and max-height properties below:

```
.attr-marker {
    display: block;
    max-width: 12px;
    max-height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 12px;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    /*If required*/
    overflow:hidden
}
```