# Html background color width adjust based on content text

Tags: html, css

I have an h1 tag in which I want to apply a background color, with the max-width property. But the background color should not be applied based on content width. Can anyone help to resolve this?

Current output:

[image]

Expected output:
Should remove red mark background color without changing the HTML content(in css with max-width property). Use only css:

[image]    
[image]

```css
h1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This paragraph testing 123</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `max-width: min-content;`

Comment: Here you can find your solution :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310154/how-do-i-set-a-background-color-for-the-width-of-text-not-the-width-of-the-enti

Answer (score -1):

```css
h1 {
  max-width: 200px;
}
h1>span {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h1><span>This paragraph testing 123</span></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

I thing you can put span tag inside H1 tag

Comment: Nope, Needs to adjust via css without HTML change

Comment: Please refer my expected output diagram and compare your output.

Answer (score -1):

Since `display:block` behavior always trying to stretch of its container width so your body has 100%. But when you put `max-width:200px` it becomes limited by 200px regardless of content inside. With your mention not changing html its not so good but you can try max-width to content Width. So try tweak html or change max-width

```css
h1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  max-width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This paragraph testing 123</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

As you don't want to change HTML content,

1. Decrease max-width value

   ```css
   h1 {
     max-width: 150px;
     background-color: yellow;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <h1>This paragraph testing 123</h1>
   ```
2. Set width in percentage wise with media query for Responsive Design

   ```css
   h1 {
     background-color: yellow;
     width: 30%;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <h1>This paragraph testing 123</h1>
   ```
3. Set `max-width: min-content`

   ```css
   h1 {
     background-color: yellow;
     max-width: min-content;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <h1>This paragraph testing 123</h1>
   ```
4. Increase / Decrease Font Size

   ```css
   h1 {
     background-color: yellow;
     max-width: 200px;
     font-size: 40px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <h1>This paragraph testing 123</h1>
   ```

Answer (score -2):

i faced this problem in client project, I searched many option but its not working properly, then finally I found this solution using "SELECTION" text you can set background cover on Text using JavaScript it support in all browser.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  let resEle = document.querySelector("h1");
    $("h1").hover(
        function () {
            window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(this);
        },
        function () {
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(this);
        }
    );
});
```

```css
h1 {
  max-width: 200px;
}

h1::selection{
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This paragraph testing 123 </h1>
</body>
</html>
```